# creating an expression using numbers and charater operator

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to create and expression from two or more numbers and character operator. The exact scenario is that i have two number for eg.

```
    float a = 10.1, b = 10.2;
```

and a character operator

```
    char ch = '+';
```

Now i have to create an expression that would look like

```
    float c = 10.1 '+' 10.2;
```

i.e. i want to apply the operator mentioned in char variable "ch" between the two float numbers i have. So in this case the charater is '+' so i want to create the expression where both the float values will be added, if '-' then substraction etc. All the values will actually be supplied by the user so want to create an expression and than perform the operation.

Now one solution I thought of is to have switch case for different operators and that would do the trick. Another one is below:

```
    float a = 10.1, b = 20.3;
    char ch = '+';
    string result = "";
    ostringstream os;
    os << a;
    result += os.str();
    os.str("");
    os << b;
    result += ch + os.str();
```

Now I wrote the above snippet so that I can create the expression based on user input and than return that expression so that it can be evaluated it in another procedure.

I am not sure if that's possible. I mean the switch case solution seems to be fine where i evaluate the expression here itself and return the output value, but just wanted to know if there is a way to return the expression to another function and then evaluate it there? 
In tcl scripting language we have a command "expr" which does the same job and so was wondering if we have any such ability to do the same in c++. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but your code to create the string is ridiculously complicated. Here’s the same code in three lines: `ostringstream os; os << a << ch << b; string result = os.str();`

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I just copied the code from an example online to get the resolution. Did not do any code optimization to meet my expectations. Long way to deadline you know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key to your question is in considering the `expression` as an object.  You're using C++, which some consider an object-oriented programming language, right? :)  Consider writing a `class Expression` that follows the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  An `Expression` might be just a simple value:

```
Expression(10.1)
```

It could also represent the addition of two subordinate `Expression`s:

```
Expression(Expression(10.1) + Expression(20.3))
```

Or to give you a further hint:

```
Expression('+', Expression(10.1), Expression(20.3))
```

Make `Expression` hold the operators and operands of the expression without actually evaluating it.  Then you are free to construct it in one place in your program, then pass that to another place to actually evalute it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a wealth of expression parsing libraries. While I haven’t used any of them myself I have heard good things about [muParser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7773/Fast-Mathematical-Expressions-Parser).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is another assignment/homework and you don't pursue fully featured expression parser, here is the solution as simple as it could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::stringstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

float compute(float a, float b, char op) {
    switch(op) {
    case '+':
        return a + b;
    case '-':
        return a - b;

    // You may add more operations in the similar way.

    default:
        cout << "Operation is not supported." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // These guys are here to simulate user input.
    float input_a  = 10.1;
    float input_b  = 20.3;
    char  input_op = '+';

    stringstream ss;

    ss << input_a << input_op << input_b;

    // If you really make it interactive, then the program actually starts here.
    float a;
    float b;
    char  op;

    // You simply read operands and operator from some input stream,
    // which in case of interactive program could be `std::cin`.
    ss >> a;
    ss >> op;
    ss >> b;  

    // Print the result of computation.
    cout << compute(a, b, op) << endl;
}
```

If you want to handle more complex situations, like evaluation of nested expressions, possibly including parentheses functionality, then I'd suggest that you read first 4 chapters of the classical **[Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)**. It really took me around 1-2 weeks to be able to write LR-parser for ANSI C, which is somewhat much more complicated than your problem.

Your task is very simple and can be described with a toy context-free grammar which doesn't even require LL-parser to handle. Anyway to understand, why and how, I encorage you to read this book.

Comment: Haroogan, thanks for your answer but I am looking for a way to do this without using switch case. Using switch, i agree it would be the simplest way and that's what i mentioned in my question details also. But just looking for something similar to the tcl scripting command "expr" if exists or possible in c++.

Comment: You can wrap `a`, `b`, and `op` into a class say `Expression` with proper functionality (something like @Richard Walters already suggested). And pass objects of this class around your code. However, you have to realize that at some point, when time comes to actually evaluate this expression, you have no choice but to use `switch`/`case` or something similar.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I was thinking about it and i actually have to parse the operator to evaluate the expression and switch case is the simplest way to do that. thanks again Harrogan. Appreciate your suggestions everyone.

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look.